# linux QtCreator как скомпилировать проект с использованием динамической библиотеки

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator

В общем, у меня есть проект на Qt, мне нужно чтобы он скомпилировался с зависимостью от libQtCore.so, и чтобы в исполняемом файле не было статической библиотеки. Оно так работает по умолчанию или нужно что-то делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно специально собрать статическую библиотеку, а динамически по умолчанию